# Multiplying Case statements in where caluse

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT s.samplename, 
       s.sampletype, 
       s.specimancateg, 
       s.panel, 
       s.plateid, 
       s.status, 
       s.tarikh, 
       s.sampletype2, 
       s.geneticanalyzer, 
       s.positive, 
       s.negative, 
       s.allelicladder, 
       s.kitname, 
       UD1a.allel, 
       UD2a.allel 
FROM   samples s 
       INNER JOIN ud1 UD1a 
               ON s.samplename = UD1a.samplename 
       INNER JOIN ud2 UD2a 
               ON s.samplename = UD2a.samplename 
WHERE  ( CASE 
           WHEN ( Regexp_like(UD2a.allel, '(.*1|.*2|.*3|.*4){4}', 'n') ) THEN ( 
           CASE 
             WHEN 
         Regexp_count(UD2a.allel, ',') + 1 != 4 THEN 0 
           ELSE 
           1 
           END ) 
         END ) + ( CASE 
                     WHEN ( Regexp_like(UD1a.allel, '(.*1){1}', 'n') ) THEN ( 
                     CASE 
                       WHEN 
                     Regexp_count(UD1a.allel, ',') + 1 != 1 THEN 0 
                     ELSE 1 
                     END ) 
                   END ) >= 1;
```

If i have two samples like this:

```
UD1:    
|SampleName|Allel    
|F1        |1    
|F2        |1,2,3,4   
UD2:    
|SampleName|Allel    
|F1        |1    
|F2        |1,2,3,4
```

it is my understanding that the result should contain both samples but i only get samlpe F2. why?

Comment: @toha Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing ELSE options in your outer CASE statement, so you are trying to add NULL to a number and it will fail regardless

That is, you have something like

```
CASE WHEN x1 THEN CASE WHEN x3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END END
```

but need something like

```
CASE WHEN x1 THEN CASE WHEN x3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ELSE ? END
```

Personally, I'd avoid nesting and go with a simpler syntax of

```
CASE WHEN x1 AND x2 .. WHEN x1 ... WHEN x2... ELSE...END
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it was the missing else